# How can I programmatically set this tablelayout to have equal column widths for Android?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to create the rows below the table heading programmatically, but they are spilling over and I am not sure how to split them up to only take up 25% of the width each?

Here is the code for the row creation:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(activity);
lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
tl = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();

tl.weight = 1;
lp.height = 100;

row.setLayoutParams(lp);
row.setWeightSum(4);


tv = new TextView(getActivity());
tv.setLayoutParams(tl);
tv.setTextSize(14);
tv.setText(whotos.get(i));

tv2 = new TextView(getActivity());
tv2.setLayoutParams(tl);
tv2.setTextSize(14);
tv2.setText(documents.get(i));

tv3 = new TextView(getActivity());
tv3.setLayoutParams(tl);
tv3.setTextSize(14);
tv3.setText(directions.get(i));

tv4 = new TextView(getActivity());
tv4.setLayoutParams(tl);
tv4.setTextSize(14);
tv4.setText(thedates.get(i));


 row.addView(tv);  //tp name
row.addView(tv2); //document type
row.addView(tv3); //direction
row.addView(tv4); //date

ll.addView(row, i + 1 + tableHeadingRows);
```

Here is my code for the layout above the programmatically created rows:

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="TP"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/doc"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="Doc"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dir"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="Direction"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- draw a red line -->
        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="@color/tableHorizontalRule" />
```

[image: Image with columns stretching too far below headers, censored names and info]

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: you can also use linear layout with weight

Comment: May be you don't need to use TableLayout. This `android:layout_weight` works on `LinearLayout` better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this over to a LinearLayout, as it simplified things a bit and allowed me to easily set column weights programmatically.